# UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include the ErrorId if you contact support: 160204114-1077924 (-725360719)

Tags: sales-cloud, gack, log-a-call

I encountered an error today while attempting to use the 'Log a Call' button on the lead object. Can you please help me figure out this problem?

Comment: You will have to contact Salesforce support.

Comment: Based on gack id above here is the error 'Field Account_Manager__r does not exist. Reason: Unable to get the formula context from Account_Manager__r'. Make sure above field relationship exists.